# Correct way and place for json conversion in SpringBoot

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I'm working on a small SpringBoot project. Storing order data in a postgres database. I have a API which returns json for my frontend. 
I'm asking myself at which place exactly I should convert my data to the actual json. I know that there a several ways to do it, but I want to learn the professional way.

Let's say the order consists in the id, date, customername, productid. For this example I only need the date as order_date and the productid as product_id for my frontend when asked for a specific name.

Possible ways:

1) Using a native postgres query in my CrudRepository:

```
@Query(value="SELECT json_build_object('order_date', o.date, 'product_id', productid) 
       from order where name=:name", nativeQuery = true)
List<Object> getOrderByName(@Param("name") String name);
```

And then simply call this repository method in the controller method.
Regarding the performance doing the conversion to json might be the fastest way. 
The big downside which I'm facing now is that you can't do any calculations on the return value of the crudrepository method because it's this special postgres object. For example mocking this in a test seems complicated.

2) Selecting the whole object in the crudrepository and then creating the json in the controller:

```
Order findByName(String name);
```

In the controller I would create a HashMap and return it, assuming my
method is has a return type ResponseEntity>.

```
Order order = orderRepository.findByName("John Doe");
HashMap<String, String> jsonResult = new HashMap<>();
jsonResult.put("order_date", order.getName());
jsonResult.put("product_id", order.getProductId());
return jsonResult;
```

This has the advantage that I can do calculations on the order object I get from the database. I dont have to use the ugly sql queries and can use the advantages of my ORM system. The big disadvante is, that I always have to create this custom json at the end of each controller method which feels wrong.

3) Using JPA projections. I did not try it, but I read about it (https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections)

What's the professional way of doing this pretty standard action? How is it done in bigger enterprise applications? Do big enterprise applications even use things like jpa crudrepository or how to the interact with the database in java?

Comment: The JSON conversion will happen automatically (usually done by Jackson "automagically"), so you only need to make sure, on a given endpoint, that you return type is JSON...that's all.

Comment: But how to handle my example? I don't want to return the whole order object. I want to return just two columns and in the json they should have the specific name, as I mentioned in the example. 
what about performance

Comment: `JsonProperty` let you control the key names; `JsonView` let you control what fields you return (on what endpoint). You can also *map* your types into "return types" and declare on those only the fields/members that you want to return.

Comment: ok got it, thank you! 
But what about the case, when i want to return json which consists in several objects and variables. lets say in this specific api method i want to add a random string which doesnt belong to the order object. How to combine several objects to a new json? what would be the return type of the method, or would i now use the hashmap solution i provided in the question?

Comment: That's what I said about "return types", you can place on those what you want to return, and build them based on one or several other objects.

Comment: can you give an example

Comment: Look at the example I posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have a "standard" project structure: controllers, services, repositories, and domain models — `import`s omitted for brevity.

#### Controller(s)

```java
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/entities")
public final class TheController {
  private final TheService service;

  @GetMapping(produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
  public ResponseEntity<Collection<JpaEntity>> getAll() {
    return ResponseEntity.ok(service.searchAll());
  }

  @GetMapping(path = "{entity-id}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
  public ResponseEntity<?> getById(final @PathVariable("entity-id") String id) {
    final Optional<JpaEntity> result = service.searchById(UUID.fromString(id));
    if (result.isPresent()) {
      return ResponseEntity.ok(result.get());
    }
    return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
  }
}
```

#### Service(s)

```java
@Service
@Transactional
public class TheService {
  private TheRepository repository;

  @Transactional(readOnly = true)
  public Collection<JpaEntity> searchAll() {
    return repository.findAll();
  }

  @Transactional(readOnly = true)
  public Optional<JpaEntity> searchById(final UUID id) {
    return repository.findById(id);
  }
}
```

#### Repositories

```java
public interface TheRepository extends JpaRepository<JpaEntity, UUID> { }
```

#### Domain Model(s)

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "tb_name")
public final class JpaEntity extends AbstractPersistable<UUID> {
  @Column(name = "column1", length = 128, nullable = false)
  private String one;

  @Column(name = "column2", length = 128, nullable = false)
  private String two;

  // No-args constructor, getters, etc.
}
```

With this structure, Spring Boot will generate the appropriate JSON representation for `JpaEntity` when a response is sent to the user-agents.

**TIP:** If you want to have more control on what fields are (de)serialized, you can take advantage of the `@JsonView` annotation.

Answer (score 0):

You need an entity first which can be mapped to your table and a crud/JPA repository for that entity. You can query the repository (in controller) and control the fields (mapped to columns of the table) to be sent back by the API.

Below is an example (you need to include spring web dependency for enabling auto Jackson configuration). Here @JsonIgnore annotation, ignore the field the JSON response. But it will be available in java object.

```
@Entity
public class Order {

    @Column(name = "product_id")
    protected Long productId;

    @Column(name = "order_date")
    protected Date orderDate;

    @JsonIgnore
    @Column(name = "order_number")
    protected Date orderNumber;

    //setters and getters

}

@Transactional
public interface OrderRepo extends JpaRepository<Order, Long>{
}

@Controller
public class OrderController
{

  public OrderController(){}

  @Autowired
  OrderRepo orderRepo;

  @GetMapping(/orders/{id})
  public Order findOrder(@PathVariable("id")long id)
  {
   return orderRepo.findById(id);
  }
}
```